# Is it possible to find the return type of a boost::function from it's typedef?

Tags: boost, boost-function

Is it possible to find the return type of a boost::function purely from its typedef?

Example:

```
typedef boost::function<bool (int, float)> CallbackType1;
typedef boost::function<float (int, float)> CallbackType2;
```

How to find the return type of the above function types?

I'm not sure if using c++0x features will be possible in my target build system, but any solution is welcome.

Many Thanks Guys,
Sak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost.Function has a typedef inside it called [return_type](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/boost/functionN.html) that should do the trick:

```
typedef CallbackType1::result_type CallbackType1ReturnType;
```

No wizardry needed.